# Moving marker position inside legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a plot in which I need information encoded in line-style, color and markers.
However, when I create a legend, the markers cover a significant part of the lines, resulting in poorly recognizable line-styles. Example:

[image: markers obscuring line-style in the legend]

Is it possible to move the markers to the side (left or right), so that the whole line and its line-style is visible? Something like the following (manually moved in inkscape):

[image: markers moved to side not to obscure line-style in the legend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea could be to draw a longer handle (e.g. `plt.legend(handlelength=4.0)`). Also, instead of one point in the center, two points could be used, one at each end (`plt.legend(numpoints=2)`).

This is how an example could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1], [2, 1], ls='-.', marker='D', color='r', label='A')
plt.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], ls='--', marker='D', color='b', label='B')
plt.legend(numpoints=2, handlelength=4.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with longer handles]

A more involved approach would be to use the new [tuple handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple) ([legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)) and create tuples with two handlers. The first handler would only contain the linestyle (removing the marker) and the second handler would only contain the marker (removing the linestyle):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
from copy import copy

plt.plot([0, 1], [2, 1], ls='-.', marker='D', color='r', label='A')
plt.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], ls='--', marker='D', color='b', label='B')
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
new_handles = []
for h in handles:
    h1 = copy(h)
    h1.set_marker('')
    h2 = copy(h)
    h2.set_linestyle('')
    new_handles.append((h1, h2))
plt.legend(handles=new_handles, labels=labels, handlelength=4.0,
           handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with tuple handler]